# Handling header part in report class

Tags: header-footer, double-sided

I have a small problem with the `report` class file. Actually I need that the odd pages have chapter title and page number in the header, while the even pages should have page number and chapter title.

Sample code like this:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title here}
\section{section title here}
blahblah
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [fancyhdr package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) makes it easy to customise the headers and footers. For example

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}{}{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\newpage
Even numbered page
\newpage
Odd numbered page
\end{document}
```

Note that the special pages on which chapters begin are not affected by this (though you can change them as well if you need to).